# Semidirect products of $V_4 \ltimes_\alpha C_3$ and isomorphies

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

My task is to find all semidirect products $V_4 \ltimes_\alpha C_3$ and to find those, who are isomorphic.

First of all, I've got to find the automorphism group of $C_3$. I know, that it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z)^*$, so it has to have $3-1=2$ elements.
The $C_3$ has got three elements $a,a^2,e$, where $e=a^3$.

For an automorphism of $C_3$ I know that it has to map $e \mapsto e$, so I only have to look how the other two elements can be mapped to eachother.

The first possibility would be $\alpha_1=Id_{C_3}$ with $e \mapsto e$ $\;$, $a \mapsto a$ and $a^2 \mapsto a^2$.

The second one would be $\alpha_2$ with $e \mapsto e$ $\;$, $a \mapsto a^2$ and $a^2 \mapsto a$.

One thing I know is, if $\alpha$ is the identity then the semidirect product is the normal direct product, so my first one would deliver $V_4 \ltimes_{\alpha_1} C_3$ = $V_4 \times C_3$. Is this one isomorphic to a known group like $C_n$ or $S_n$?

And for $\alpha_2$ I don't know how I have to go on.

Comment: Is $V_4$ the Klein $4$-group?  Direct and semidirect products are generally considered "known groups" and often have no simpler description, the point here is just to identify how many there are and when they're isomorphic.

Comment: Also, the map you really need to look at is $V_4 \to \mathrm{Aut}(C_3)$.  You get a direct product when this map is trivial.  So now you know that $\mathrm{Aut}(C_3) \simeq C_2$.  You need to start by finding all the homomorphisms $V_4 \to C_2$.

Comment: Yes, it is the Klein-4-group.
Is their a theorem that gives me the number of homomorphisms betwenn two groups? So I know how many I have to find.

Comment: I know that for a homomorphism $\phi : V_4 \to Aut(C_3)$, the neutral element of $V_4$ has to be mapped to $Id_{C_3}$.

Comment: A hint regarding $\alpha_2$: What can you say in that case about (a) the set of Sylow-$3$ subgroups of $G$, (b) the action of $G$ on that set and (c) the kernel of that action?

Comment: I haven't had this vocabulary in my lectures yet. Is it possible, not to use them directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each semidirect products $ ( \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 )\ltimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}_3$ is characterised by a homomorphism $\alpha : \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$. As you noted there are two automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_3$:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{id}: \mathbb{Z}_3 &\to \mathbb{Z}_3 & f : \mathbb{Z}_3 &\to \mathbb{Z}_3 \\
 1& \mapsto 1 & 1 &\mapsto 2 
\end{align*}

Next we determine the homomorphisms $\alpha :\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$. Each $\alpha$ is determined by its effecton on $(1,0),(0,1) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ has two elements, there are $2\cdot 2 = 4$ such homorphisms. First is the trivial map

\begin{align*}
\alpha_1: \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3) \\
x &\mapsto \operatorname{id},
\end{align*}

in which case $\left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) 
\ltimes_{\alpha_1} \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. There are also the three homomorphisms:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_2: \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3) 
& \alpha_3 : \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3) 
& \alpha_4 : \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3) \\
(0,0) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} & (0,0) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} & (0,0) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} \\
(1,0) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} & (1,0) & \mapsto f & (1,0) & \mapsto f \\
(0,1) & \mapsto f & (0,1) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} & (0,1) & \mapsto f \\
(1,1) & \mapsto f & (1,1) & \mapsto f & (1,1) & \mapsto \operatorname{id} \\
\end{align*}

So there are  four possible semidirect products $ ( \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 )\ltimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}_3$. But are they all distinct groups?

The answer is no. The homomorphisms $\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ all induce isomorphic groups. To see this, observe that $\alpha_3 = \alpha_2 \circ \phi$ and $\alpha_4 = \alpha_2 \circ \psi$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the automorphisms:
\begin{align*}
\phi: \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2
& \psi: \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 &\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \\
(0,0) & \mapsto (0,0) & (0,0) & \mapsto (0,0) \\
(1,0) & \mapsto (0,1) & (1,0) & \mapsto (1,1) \\
(0,1) & \mapsto (1,0) & (0,1) & \mapsto (0,1) \\
(1,1) & \mapsto (1,1) & (1,1) & \mapsto (1,0) \\
\end{align*}

It follows that $\left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_2} \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_3} \mathbb{Z}_3 $ via the map:
\begin{align*}
\Theta:\left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_2} \mathbb{Z}_3 &\to \left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_3} \mathbb{Z}_3  \\
((a,b),c) &\mapsto \left( \phi^{-1}(a,b),c \right)
\end{align*}

A similar calculation yields, $\left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_2} \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \left( \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \right) \ltimes_{\alpha_4} \mathbb{Z}_3 $.

Thus there are two distict semidirect products $ ( \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 )\ltimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: I really thank you for this solution!
In your definition of $\alpha_4$ are mistakes in the last two mappings. You have there another two times the element $(0,0)$. These should be $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$.